# Insert Rows in Excel using Python

Tags: python, xlwings

I am using python 3.6.4, and I want to insert rows in excel using xlwings.... however I am not able to. I used the code **ws.range('1:1').insert('down')** . i am getting the error
'Range' object has no attribut 'Insert'

Is there an alternative to this that i can use?

Comment: What is your version of xlwings? try doing `import xlwings` and then `print(xlwings.__version__)`

Comment: Xlwings version 0.11.5

Comment: I think insert is introduced in v0.16.4 (Dec 17, 2019). Either way the command works with the latest v0.26.x.